# Spring 3.2 Caching NamespaceHandler for ehcache

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

**strong text**I am  having following error while running Java SE +Spring application. I have found similar problem over intenet and this web site but could not find proper solution. I think the problem is missing jar file.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring]
Offending resource: class path resource [Spring-Module.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1435)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:185)
    at
```

**Spring.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring
    http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd
    ">
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringExample</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringExample</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>   
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>    
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>   
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use `ehcache-spring-annotations`, but I don't see the dependency in your POM.

Try to add :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

BTW, if you want yo use native Spring support for `@Cacheable`, you don't need this dependency. So just remove

```
http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring
http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd
```

from your `Spring.xml` file.

Comment: while using native Spring support how I define cachemanager. Could you write sample Spring.xml.

Comment: Have a look to : http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/spring-31-cache-abstraction-tutorial.html or official doc : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Comment: http://www.briandupreez.net/2010/06/spring-aspectj-ehcache-method-caching.html link is well for native Spring cache support